# How to use JpegBitmapDecoder in Systems.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, performance

Is there a way that I can use the BitmapFrame returned from JpegBitmapDecoder in the UserControl.OnPaint() method?  I was told that the performance of JPEG decoding from Systems.Windows.Media.Imaging is much better than the one in GDI+ used by Systems.Windows.Forms library.  However, my application is written with Systems.Windows.Forms library already and I don't want to change everything.  All I need is a faster way to decompress the JPEG frame and draw it in OnPaint() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.  Here are the sample code:

```
JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(pixelStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
BitmapFrame frame = decoder.Frames[0];
frame.CopyPixels(pixelBuffer, stride, 0);
```

pixelBuffer is a preallocated byte array.  And then I can use it to construct a Bitmap use in OnPaint().

Answer (score 0):

To use it in a Windows.Forms project add these references:

- WindowsBase.DLL
- PresentationCore.DLL
- System.Xaml.DLL

Then call this method:

```
protected static Bitmap JpegToBitmap(Stream jpg)
{
    JpegBitmapDecoder ldDecoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(jpg, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    BitmapFrame lfFrame = ldDecoder.Frames[0];
    Bitmap lbmpBitmap = new Bitmap(lfFrame.PixelWidth, lfFrame.PixelHeight);
    Rectangle lrRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, lbmpBitmap.Width, lbmpBitmap.Height);
    BitmapData lbdData = lbmpBitmap.LockBits(lrRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, (lfFrame.Format.BitsPerPixel == 24 ? PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb : PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb));
    lfFrame.CopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, lbdData.Scan0, lbdData.Height * lbdData.Stride, lbdData.Stride);
    lbmpBitmap.UnlockBits(lbdData);

    return lbmpBitmap;
}
```